# Логика приложения ( автопилот )

Tags: javascript, логика

Изучаю потихоньку язык javascript и столкнулся с  такой проблемой, как построение логики ( отдельной функции )

Условно говоря, дана сетка 10 х 10 квадратов, как поле для морского боя.

[image: Сетка]

Есть также одноклеточный "кораблик", который можно переместить по полю на 1 клетку вверх, вниз, влево , вправо или по диагонали. Одно перемещение в любую сторону за один ход.

Чтобы переместиться из клетки А1 в клетку Д1,  нужно 4 раза сделать ход вправо.
Чтобы переместиться из клетки Б2 в клетку Г4,  нужно 2 раза сделать ход под диагонали.
И пр, и пр...

Вопрос в чем:
Как проще выстроить логику функции, которая перемещала бы "кораблик" после клика на нужный квадрат ?
То есть, пользователь не пошагово перемещает квадрат к цели, а кликнул на нужный квадрат и дальше работает программа.

Я начал с определения двух переменных:

1. Где кораблик сейчас.
2. Куда нужно попасть.
   А потом просто стал описывать маршрут для всех возможных стартовых положений во все возможные пункты назначения...
   (  Если кораблик в А1 , а нужно в Б1, то сделать ход вправо
   Если кораблик в А1 , а нужно в В1, то сделать ход вправо, ход вправо
   Если кораблик в А1 , а нужно в В2, то сделать ход вправо, ход по диагонали вправо вниз )
   И так далее

Но блин, такой огород получается...

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант - определять положение корабля относительно конечной точки после каждого хода. Например из А1 надо попасть в Б2. Стоим на А1:

1. Мы находимся левее конечной клетки? Двигаемся вправо.
2. Мы находимся левее конечной клетки? Нет.
3. Мы находимся выше конечной клетки? Да, двигаемся вниз.
4. Мы находимся выше конечной клетки? Нет.

Ну и перед каждым ходом проверять находимся ли мы в конечной клетке, плюс не забывать обрабатывать граничные условия.

Comment: Круто, спасибо!